# MVC DropdownlistFor not reverting to default value on null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a page which sets the controls on another page to required (-1), disabled (0) or optional (null) from a db table.

They all use the same Viewbag param as the source.

here is the dropdown code which is repeated x number of times.

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Control1, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.StateList, "Optional", new {@class = "form-control"})
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Control2, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.StateList, "Optional", new {@class = "form-control"})
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Control3, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.StateList, "Optional", new {@class = "form-control"})
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Control4, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.StateList, "Optional", new {@class = "form-control"})
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Control5, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.StateList, "Optional", new {@class = "form-control"})
```

StateList Contains

```
    List<SelectListItem> states = new List<SelectListItem>();
    states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Required", Value = "-1" });
    states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Disabled", Value = "0" });
    ViewBag.StateList = states;
```

This loads up correctly if they are all null, they all display optional.

if i set each one to either required or disabled it works correctly as well.

if i leave the first couple to optional and set number 3 to required and leave the rest it saves correctly in the db as

```
null,null,-1,null,null,etc
```

but when it displays the first two are optional but all others are set to whatever i set in control 3 be it required or disabled.

So what should display as

Optional,Optional,Required,Optional,Optional etc

It displays as

Optional,Optional,Required,Required,Required.

Any ideas?

**** EDIT ***

Ok Definitly a binding issue to the Dropdownlistfor...
i replaced them with

```
        <select id="Control1" name="Control1" class="form-control">
            @foreach (SelectListItem option in ViewBag.StateList)
            {
                if (option.Value == Model.Control1.ToString())
                {
                    <option value="@option.Value" selected='selected'>@option.Text</option>
                }
                else
                {
                    <option value="@option.Value">@option.Text</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
```

and it works as expected....

this unfortunately turns one line of code into 13.... which i'm not particularly happy about.... so hopefully this info will help in finding a solution using the intended use of dropdownlist for....

Comment: Your 3rd and 4th DropDown, what does the `@Html.DropDownListFor` look like?

Comment: exactly the same just with a different prop binding eg `@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Control3, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.StateList, "Optional", new {@class = "form-control"})` , `@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Control4, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.StateList, "Optional", new {@class = "form-control"})`

Comment: If you put a breakpoint, do `Control4` and `Control5` have the values you expect?

Comment: When the record comes from the db 4 & 5 have the values i'm expecting so its definitely not a source data issue but a display or binding problem. They are being passed the correct values (null) but are displaying the first non null value that's displayed.

Comment: @LRiley Make your `Control4` & `Control5` props `nullable`

Comment: @Izzy all control props are nullable, they are capable of being null because if i made control 6 required 4 and 5 would be optional (null) but 7+ would all be required regardless of null values